# Splitting up Apache2 and Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

Currently we have Apache2 and Tomcat8 running on the same server, with MySQL backend.  We want to go from 2 tier to 3 tier, that is putting a Apache server in front of Tomcat.  Right now we don't need a load-balancer nor reverse proxy. Nor is there a firewall between Apache2 server and Tomcat8 server. Nor is Apache2 serving any static content.

Simply need to log onto the Apache2 server and in the browser type localhost and have it pull up the webapp running on the backend Tomcat8. I have done telnet tests and confirmed that port 8009 is up and running.  I've tried to update the workers.properties file, but getting a 503 error.

Let's say our set up is:
Apache2 server is 111.111.11.132
Tomcat8 server is 111.111.11.122

I have probe up at running by:
http://111.111.11.122/probe

In the Apache2 httpd.conf file I have added:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyPass /probe http://111.111.11.122:8080/probe
ProxyPassReverse /probe http://111.111.11.122:8080/probe
```

I then go to internet explorer on the apache2 server and put in:
http://localhost/probe/*

It challenges me for the probe userid and password and then I get the following error:
The webpage cannot be found

Comment: Technically, Apache in front of Tomcat **is** a reverse proxy. You aren't sharing any config, what you need is to set ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse in your Apache config. You can send traffic to ajp:// in your ProxyPassXXX directives as Tomcat is configured for that according to what you said.

Comment: Adding to @EugèneAdell's comment, on the Apache installed system, connect to the Tomcat installed system's DNS name.  Not localhost, since Tomcat is on the other machine.  Show your config in the questino.

Comment: @Nic3500 The question says they are "running on the same server". But your idea is good, as we don't know whether Tomcat is listening on localhost or not, and how Apache is proxying.

Comment: @EugèneAdell: my bad, when he said "going from 2 tier to 3 tier" I assumed he would move the web to another system, since that is what I have done many times.